# NTFS-Bootcamp-partition thinks it is a FAT partition

Tags: macos, bootcamp, parallels-desktop, ntfs

[image]I'm running 10.8.3 Snow Leopard and installed Windows 7 x64 using Bootcamp.
Both system are running fine.

I couldn't use the bootcamp-partition inside in Parallels and then I read about Tuxera NTFS blocking it. Therefore I uninstalled Tuxera NTFS. Ever since then the disk utility shows the Bootcamp partition as a FAT-partition (see attached screenshot). Re-installing Tuxera NTFS didn't help either.

Error checking and repairing with the disk utility doesn't help.
I tried unmounting the whole drive/all partitions via disk utility on another Mac (using FireWire-boot). It didn't work sadly.

Does anyone have a clue what else I can do? The Bootcamp-Windows is already set up with my work-environment which took a long time so I don't want to reinstall.

Comment: Aside from displaying the filesystem type incorrectly is there anything that's not working for you?  p.s. you didn't attach the screen shot

Comment: I attached the screenshot. Parallels doesn't recognize the Bootcamp partition so I can't use it in Parallels.

Comment: Bootcamp still works, right? If you boot into Windows what does Window report as the filesystem type?

Comment: Bootcamp works. In Windows the partition shows up as NTFS.

Comment: Running into this issue as well, years later.